# Is it normal to say that something "Breaks in two"?

Tags: word-usage

:)
I was wondering if one could say in a poetic way that

> "a seed breaks in two"

...or should one say

> "breaks apart"

or even something totally different?

Comment: Welcome to English language learners RedDave, this is a great first question! Please take a moment to [take the tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [visit the help centre](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help) for more information.

Comment: Something like a ***seed*** would more likely ***break open*** than ***break apart***. The former alludes to making it possible for life-giving stuff *inside* the seed to get out and do whatever it needs to do in the outside world. The latter is more about being (irreparably) ***broken*** (and hence probably "non-functional").

Answer (score 1):

"**to break in/into two**" is quite a common way of saying it. You could also say "**to break in half**".

[image: The Ngram]

Judging by Google Ngram the "**break in two**" is more common.

"**to break apart**" may imply two or more pieces.

---

Now to the question about **seeds**. You normally wound't break a seed; you would **crack it open**, **crack it**, or **split it**.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your helpful reply! It's not about breaking a seed in two but about what happens "naturally" to a seed...so rather in a more passive intransitiv meaning I guess.

Comment: @RedDave Naturally it **cracks open**...

Answer (score 0):

"*Broke in two*" specifically means that something separated into *two* distinct pieces.

Something that "breaks *apart*" also ends up as separate pieces - the pieces are *apart* from one another. It could imply more than two pieces, although "breaks *up*" is more often used to mean breaking into many pieces.

If you simply mean that something *splits open* to reveal what is inside, but remains as one piece, you would be better saying that it "splits open", "breaks open" or "cracks open".

In the context of something like your seed example, where the contents of something have grown to force the exterior to break, you could say "*burst* open", "burst apart", or even just "burst". As an opinion, I feel this is the most poetic word - "bursting" paints a very vivid word picture of something swelling until it cannot be contained any longer.